# Do higher combos increase my damage?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I wonder if the size of the combo meter has influence on anything if you don't have runes, which have special effect for higher combo counts. I am aware that with getting combos you can use special skills like executes, but this is not what I mean.

[image: screenshot with arrow on strike number]

Comment: Are you talking about whether the size of the combo meter increases the damage of your strikes?

Comment: No the damage of normal weapon hits or skills or any influence in general

Comment: So what you're asking is if you do more damage if your combo counter is higher?

Comment: Yes or if the skill damage is higher. I wonder If there is any influence when you have a high combo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combos do not directly increase your damage, but higher combos do award more experience at the end of the combat. At the end of the combat, your highest combo is multiplied by 10 and awarded as experience for Talion. There is also a Tier 5 ability that doubles your attack damage while you have a Hit Streak active.

Comment: That is the answer I have searched. Didn't think about EXP and so it has an advantage to get higher combos.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Higher hit steak values also allow you to break wooden shields & power past berserkers' parrys.